# Assign default value for struct field

Tags: go

I want to assign default value for struct field in Go. I am not sure if it is possible but while creating/initializing object of the struct, if I don't assign any value to the field, I want it to be assigned from default value. Any idea how to achieve it?

```
type abc struct {
    prop1 int
    prop2 int  // default value: 0
}
obj := abc{prop1: 5}
// here I want obj.prop2 to be 0
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is not possible. The best you can do is use a constructor method:

```
type abc struct {
    prop1 int
    prop2 int  // default value: 0
}

func New(prop1 int) abc {
    return abc{
        prop1: prop1,
        prop2: someDefaultValue,
    }
}
```

But also note that all values in Go *automatically* default to their zero value. The zero value for an `int` is already `0`. So if the default value you want is literally `0`, you already get that for free.  You only need a constructor if you want some default value other than the zero value for a type.